# How do I simulate automatic Tab creation in a macOS window with the Option key held down?

Tags: macos, nswindow, nstabview

### Default behavior: The option key forces a Tab

I have a document based macOS app, with a custom `NSDocumentController`. The app can handle two types of documents, each with their own windows and views.

Now, if the user has turned off the option to always create Tabs in windows, `cmd-N` will always create a fresh window.

And if the user types `cmd-option-N`, **the framework automatically creates a Tab** inside the front window regardless of the global or app's tabbing preference. This requires no extra programming on my part.

So far, so good.

Now, I have a *secondary* document type that gets created by `cmd-shift-N`. This creates, thanks to my custom DocumentController, a new window each time as well, as expected.

### The challenge: Achieve the same with an additional modifier

I want the user to be able to type `cmd-shift-option-N` to create a new Tab inside an existing document window, just like `cmd-option-N` does for the primary document type.

However, it seems that the framework only handles a plain `cmd-option-N` for auto-creating Tabs. For other modifier combinations (like here, with shift), this doesn't appear to work: If I have set up a menu only for `cmd-shift-N`, then pressing `cmd-shift-option-N` will just beep. And if I add an explicit menu for `cmd-shift-option-N`, it creates a new window and not a Tab as desired.

So I need to emulate the behavior of turning the new document into a Tab instead of into a new Window. How do I do that, with the global tabbing more set to not create tabs?

Answer (score 0):

By trial-and-error I came up with the following solution.

This requires a `NSDocument` subclass, let's call it 'CustomDocument`.

In it, I add a flag that controls whether I want to add the new window as a tab:

```objc
@interface CustomDocument : NSDocument
   @property BOOL foceIntoTab;
@end
```

Then I need to implement a custom handler for creating the window controller, in which I first determine if there's already a window to which I'd add the other one, then create the new controller, and finally add it as a tab:

```objc
- (void)makeWindowControllers // override
{
    __block NSWindow *frontWindow = nil;
    if (self.forceIntoTab) {
        // Find the topmost window that's of my document type
        [NSApp enumerateWindowsWithOptions:NSWindowListOrderedFrontToBack usingBlock:^(NSWindow *window, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([window.windowController.document isKindOfClass:CustomDocument.class]) {
                frontWindow = window;
                *stop = YES;
            }
        }];
    }

    NSWindowController *windowController = [[NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Custom Controller"];

    if (frontWindow) {
        [frontWindow.tabGroup addWindow:windowController.window];
        [windowController.window orderFront:frontWindow];
        [windowController.window makeKeyWindow];
    }

    NSViewController *viewController = windowController.contentViewController;
    [viewController setRepresentedObject:self];
    [self addWindowController:windowController];
}
```

What's left is to set `forceIntoTab` when creating a new window via the menu bar. I could do this, for instance, in my custom DocumentController class:

```objc
- (nullable __kindof NSDocument *)makeUntitledDocumentOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError // override
{
    CustomDocument *doc = [super makeUntitledDocumentOfType:typeName error:outError];
    doc.forceIntoTab = YES;
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: New documents are always added as tab? How do you catch the option key?

Comment: @Willeke I do not understand your first part of the question. For the second part - I add an alternative menu item that uses the option key in the shortcut, and with its own action handler.